# How to access in OrderedDict in Python previous key and value?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to access in OrderedDict in Python previous key and value ? I am trying to calculate distance of every point from start point through polyline. In self._line key is pair of coordinates (x, y) and values is distance from polyline beginning through segments.
In code bellow for start position distance is zero, for next are sum to all polyline segments.
Is there more elegant way to do this without flags prev_x, prev_y

```
    self._line = OrderedDict()
    prev_x, prev_y = None, None
    for x, y in passed_line:
        self._line[(x, y)] = 0 if  prev_x is None and prev_y is None else self._line[(prev_x, prev_y)] + math.sqrt((x - prev_x) * (x - prev_x) + (y - prev_y) * (y - prev_y))
        prev_x, prev_y = x, y
```

Comment: You can clean this up somewhat by using a little Algebra.  Remember that `NxN=N^2`.  So, you can change `(x - prev_x) * (x - prev_x) + (y - prev_y) * (y - prev_y)` to `(x - prev_x)**2 + (y - prev_y)**2`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` to enumerate over a list pair-wise, something like this:

```
distance = OrderedDict()
distance[line[0]] = 0
for (x1, y1), (x2, y2) in zip(line, line[1:]):
    d = ((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2) ** 0.5
    distance[(x2, y2)] = distance[(x1, y1)] + d
```

Here's an example with sample inputs:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>>
>>> line = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (0, 5), (6, 7)]
>>> 
>>> distance = OrderedDict()
>>> distance[line[0]] = 0
>>> for (x1, y1), (x2, y2) in zip(line, line[1:]):
...     d = ((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2) ** 0.5
...     distance[(x2, y2)] = distance[(x1, y1)] + d
... 
>>> distance
OrderedDict([((1, 2), 0), ((3, 4), 2.8284271247461903), ((0, 5), 5.99070478491457), ((6, 7), 12.31526010525133)])
```